# mysql query to draw a linear chart

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, charts

I would like to draw a linear chart in my xhtml page. In the abscissa, I want to put the months, and in the ordinate I want to put the quantity of orders per month.
In your opinion, is it possible to create a mysql query to return a list in which each row contains one month and quantity of orders in the second attribute.

here is my table :

[image]

and here is the sql query to retrieve all date_envoi :

```
select date_envoi from commande;
```

here is the image :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `GROUP` records by `MONTH` and `YEAR`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_envoi, '%M %Y') AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS order_quantity
FROM commande
GROUP BY YEAR(date_envoi), MONTH(date_envoi);
```

**EDIT:** To get month in numeric format:

```
SELECT YEAR(date_envoi) AS year,
       MONTH(date_envoi) AS month,
       COUNT(*) AS order_quantity
FROM commande
GROUP BY YEAR(date_envoi), MONTH(date_envoi);
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
SELECT `month`, SUM(order_quantity) AS order_quantity
FROM(

    SELECT MONTH(date_envoi) AS month,
           COUNT(*) AS order_quantity
    FROM commande
    GROUP BY MONTH(date_envoi)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 AS month, 0 order_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 AS month, 0 order_quantity
) a
GROUP BY `month`
ORDER BY `month` ASC;
```

Comment: thank you, it works but please, how I can  have the numeric month

Comment: See updated answer. Also you can get it using `DATE_FORMAT(date_envoi, '%m-%Y')`

Comment: also please, how I can define the year because I often  would like to use a year from current month last year from curent month

Comment: You can get year using YEAR(date_envoi). Year will be needed when you have data for at-least two years.

Comment: currently I use only two months August and September, but I want all months of the year are displayed in the result of the query, in your opinion how I can achieve this

Comment: in others words, I want to having all months and if there is no record  in one month I want to put zero in this month

Comment: Yes but it's not that simple with query. See updated query should work for you.

Comment: thank you very much @Omesh, it works fine, here is the capture : [http://s7.postimage.org/x6c4l6yln/Capture.png] but I don't understand  how to design the query, can you explain for me

Comment: You're welcome! :) In this query you need to add all the 12 months using `UNION ALL` operation, Also you can count total number of orders using `GROUP BY` aggregate function. See: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/index.php